# How to see controls which are below the bottom of screen in designer

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I have a StackPanel in ScrollViewer with many TextBlock+TextBox (so on the screen I see same scrolling list view like in phone's standard Settings page).

In VS's or Blend's designer is it any simple way to see controls which are bellow the bottom of screen? (I need some kind of scrolling in designer). It must be something simple. Now I am switching off visibility of upper controls to see lower controls and it is boring.

Comment: i don't think it's possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `d:DesignHeight` to a larger value, such as 2000 (the maximum height), and Expression Blend will allow you to see content that otherwise would require scrolling.

[Example screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1744224/viewpub.png)

Comment: May be it works with silverlight but not working with Windows Phone 7

Comment: The example screenshot is from one of my Windows Phone apps. Soooo

Comment: My mistake. It works, but only once it is set. After rebuilding the visual height is small as before though the value is still 2000.

Comment: Yes, a known quirk in Blend. Not much to do about that. But you shouldn't need to rebuild during the design-process anyway.